# Moto Z Force unlocked?

Tags: motorola, carriers

Next week I'm going to us and I will buy a new phone. I was thinking of buying a Moto Z Force. But I heard it is only available for Verizon. I'm from Brazil and would like to know if even if the version from the Motorola site is locked for Verizon and if I would have any problems in using this phone here in Brazil.

Comment: Be aware that all Verizon devices are not carrier locked, but use a custom version of the device's normal Android OS that does not allow the bootloader to be unlocked (thus it cannot be rooted or use custom ROMs), you will not get OTA updates since they require a connection to Verizon's network, you will get a TON of Verizon bloat, and you will get constantly nagged that the SIM is Unknown (although it should work). MMS could be an issue as well, you may need a 3rd party app. Moto is supposed be to releasing unlock Z variant, I would wait. (Actually, it is up for pre-order now on moto.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Verizon uses LTE bands 2, 4, and 13.](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Cheat-sheet-which-4G-LTE-bands-do-AT-T-Verizon-T-Mobile-and-Sprint-use-in-the-USA_id77933)

Brazilian carriers appear to use [3, 7, 28, and 38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks#Americas).  As such, you should by default expect US Verizon phones not to work with LTE in Brazil since there are no overlapping bands.

**However**, the Verizon Z Force [supports bands 2-5, 7, and 13](http://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-force-droid-edition).  So it's quite possible that it would work on some Brazilian carriers using bands 3 and 7.

(The same basic process of finding overlap applies for 3G bands, GSM voice, etc. if you don't care about LTE specifically.)

You should contact Motorola directly to find out whether the version they sell is locked, and (if so) whether it can be easily unlocked.

Comment: FYI... Your information on the Moto Z Force seems incorrect. The Verizon only model only supports LTE bands 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, and 13 according to http://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-z-force-droid-edition but it doesn't really effect your answer technically.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks!  I've updated my answer to use your reference.

Answer (score -2):

Yes , **US VZ** Telephony has a different **4G** protocol . You will not be able to use **4G** in Brazil.

Comment: At least some Brazilian carriers have LTE, same protocol as Verizon.  That's not the issue.